# How to display X-Y data with different colors using arcmap

Tags: arcgis-10.2, scatterplot

I have a list of lat/lon coordinates for data points that I want to put on a map.  I want to have the size and/or color of the points to change based on additional columns on the excel sheet with the coordinates (kind of like a bubble chart).  Is it possible to do this in GIS? I am using arcmap 10.2.

Comment: If you have ArcGIS Online you can map directly from Excel using [ArcGIS Maps for Office](http://www.esri.com/software/maps-for-office) which I think will do what you're wanting

Comment: I am working in ArcMap 10.2

Answer (score 1):

This is quintessential gis. The process depends on your available software.

Esri
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-a-layer-using-categories.htm

Or

Qgis (open source) 
http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html

You could start either process by importing csv with your x/y values and the symbology fields.